# What is the rustified way to wait on multiple tasks

Tags: multithreading, rust

In some programming languages (like .NET), you can wait on a list of thread handles. You can wait on all of them to complete, or just one. I didn't see anything like that in Rust.

It got me wondering, what is the proper way to monitor all threads.

For example, an application starts up 10 threads. And if any one of them were to terminate (either normally, abnormally or panic'd), the process should gracefully exit. What would be the appropriate design pattern in rust for something like this?

EDIT:  Here is a better use case.  I have a thread that's serves an HTTP API like so...

```
let mut app_server: Server = tide::Server::with_state(app.clone());
app_server.at("/health_check").get(|_| async { Ok("Ok") });
// .... additional other API end points
let listen_result = app_server.listen(http_addr.clone()).await;
```

Now I have other threads running and a single thread monitoring (perhaps main) all of them. When one thread terminates for ANY REASON, let's say it exits gracefully, my monitoring thread will need to call listen_result.cancel to gracefully shutdown the HTTP API Server.

The examples I've seen is iterating over all the join handles and join to them, but that doesn't work if the first one you are joining to isn't the thread that exits.

I'm using std::thread.

```
let thread_handle = thread::spawn(move || {
    match block_on(listener_thread(/*some params*/)) {
        Ok(_) => {
            info!(...);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            error!(...);
        }
    }
});
```

Edit #2 - This question is more about trying to understand how such a use case would be addressed in Rust and best practices. I assumed threads would be involved, but based on comments it's clear I need tokio and async tasks.

Comment: You can [select](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) or [join](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.join.html) on [tokio](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/index.html) [task](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/index.html) [handles](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html) (or just futures) in a very similar way

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand completely. Are you asking if you can gather a list of async methods, or if you can check the status of each request?

Comment: @targetXING, please see my edit to include a better use case for this.

Comment: tide doesn't have graceful shutdown, [I thought](https://github.com/http-rs/tide/issues/528)? If shutting down the http server is all, is there much of a difference to just std::process::exit()? Depending on what you want, you could use watcher threads that join the worker threads and send a token to a channel, or [`spawn_blocking`](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/task/fn.spawn_blocking.html), but without knowing what your threads do and what exactly needs to be done on shutdown, this question isn't really answerable.

Comment: Looking at the example you just added, you should just use [`spawn`](https://docs.rs/async-std/latest/async_std/task/fn.spawn.html) instead of `thread::spawn` + `block_on` as `async-std` already uses multiple threads. That'll make it much easier to use the `FuturesUnordered` that  @cdhowie suggested. Also, you might want to read up on the ecosystem a bit, async rust may bite you if you just hop in blindly.

Comment: @Caesar - that's the goal. I'm trying to make the transition to Rust and trying to get familiar with the ecosystem and best practices, hence the question. And I'm having a hard time finding information on this subject.

Comment: @Caesar, it might also be helpful to know that this application is going to be running on an embedded system with very limited resources.

Comment: There is no way to do what you want in any programming language that runs on top of a POSIX thread system because POSIX just doesn't have a way to wait for any thread. Nor there is a need, because an individual thread cannot crash. A threads either exits gracefully or brings the entire process down. You can use normal asynchronous primitives to report events such as "this thread is about to exit".

Comment: @tdemay An embedded system with limited resources and 10 compute threads? Weird. At this time, I'm thinking your entire question is ill-posed, and you never wanted to start any threads to begin with, but [tasks](https://book.async.rs/concepts/tasks). (That book also has a nice section about building a chat server with graceful shutdown. But be aware that most of the Rust async ecosystem is centered around `tokio`, not `async-std`. `tide` is an exception there.)

Comment: If you control how the threads are started (which you apparently do, since you have the handles), you can create an mpsc channel and send a message to the channel when a thread ends. The monitoring thread will listen to the channel and will therefore immediately know when any thread ends.

Comment: @Caesar, I don't really know that I need ten threads, I'm in proof of concept phase and was just speculating. I know I'll need something to monitor a state machine, and a http api listener and something to run an occasional job. Regarding the question being ill-posed or weird, this whole question was to understand Rust best practices. I'm trying to learn. If I'm approaching this wrong I want to know. Apparently I was wrong to assume threads would be required here. It's clear I need async operations. This conversation is extremely helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a built-in way to do this, and even if there were it wouldn't be that useful to you because there isn't a memory-safe way to forcibly terminate a running thread.  This means you cannot "gracefully terminate" without inserting code into your threads that will check something like an [`AtomicBool`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html) and terminate on their own, and if you are adding that type of signalling then you can also add a way to signal errors back to the main thread using a [channel](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html).

If you are wanting to proceed with basic threads, then that's what you need to do.  However, all of this boilerplate sounds a lot like what an async runtime such as [Tokio](https://tokio.rs) gives you out of the box:

- [`FuturesUnordered`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/struct.FuturesUnordered.html) gives you a way to wait for the first out of a set of futures to complete.
- If you need to terminate a task, Tokio provides [`JoinHandle::abort`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/struct.JoinHandle.html#method.abort) which will set a flag that causes the task to terminate at its next await point. Calling `abort` followed by awaiting the handle will block until the task aborts.

You could even abandon the idea of having multiple dedicated threads and just spawn tasks ad-hoc since they are lightweight.

---

Here is an example of how you might join multiple threads, signalling an error if any of them panics:

```
use std::{
    any::Any,
    panic::{catch_unwind, UnwindSafe},
    sync::mpsc,
};

struct Threads {
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Box<dyn Any + Send + 'static>>,
    receiver: mpsc::Receiver<Box<dyn Any + Send + 'static>>,
}

impl Threads {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (sender, receiver) = mpsc::channel();

        Self { sender, receiver }
    }

    pub fn spawn(&self, f: impl FnOnce() + Send + UnwindSafe + 'static) {
        let sender = self.sender.clone();

        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            if let Err(e) = catch_unwind(f) {
                // If this fails, the receiver has been dropped.  In that case
                // we don't have anyone to tell about the panic.  For that
                // reason, we ignore errors from sender.send().
                drop(sender.send(e));
            }
        });
    }

    pub fn join_all(self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Any + Send + 'static>> {
        // Drop our sender so the channel will close when all threads have
        // terminated.
        drop(self.sender);

        // Success and failure need to be swapped around; a successful receive
        // means a thread paniced, while a failed receive means the channel
        // closed because all threads terminated without an error.
        match self.receiver.recv() {
            Ok(e) => Err(e),
            Err(_) => Ok(()),
        }
    }
}
```

I've left signalling the remaining threads to terminate on an error as an exercise for you.  How you implement this will depend on what the threads are doing.  You could use an `AtomicBool` and periodically check it, for example.

Comment: The question isn't how to forcibly terminate a running thread. As I mentioned, gracefully exit. If a thread unexpectedly terminates a monitoring thread, (or main thread), will somehow signal all other threads to gracefully exit so the process can gracefully exit. I'm just learning rust. But what I'm beginning to understand is that this isn't really possible with std::thread, that you need to use something like tokio. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: see my edit for better use case.

Comment: @tdemay No, it's not correct. You can do this signalling with a channel, which I pointed out in my answer. (On a panic you transmit an error signal, otherwise if the thread terminates normally you transmit a success signal.) The point of my answer, though, is that if you're going to wire up all of this signalling to communicate between threads, you _might as well_ use an async runtime that already has all of this signalling built in.

Comment: @tdemay I've updated the answer to show a sample of how you might join multiple threads using a channel.

Comment: Thank you, but would you mind perhaps using tasks with tokio? I'm learning that threads are overkill for what I need to do. This will be running on an embedded system, so needs to be as lightweight as possible.

Comment: Right now, all I know is I need something to listen for HTTP API requests, something to monitor state machines, and something for an occasional task. And the "main" thread will need to be able to cancel the listener (if possible/or needed) if the application receives some kind of notification that it needs to terminate.

Comment: @tdemay How you'd do this in tokio depends a lot more on what you're doing with the tasks, because "wait for a bunch of tasks" may not even be the right pattern. There may be a far simpler approach. For example, you can aggregate tasks using streams to result in far more ergonomic code.

Comment: absolutely - See my comment right after the comment about tokio. Ultimately that is my real use case right now. (still just proof of concep)

Comment: Ok. So in that case you could use a channel to signal errors to the main thread. If you're using Axum or another HTTP service based on hyper, the [`with_graceful_shutdown`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.27/hyper/server/struct.Server.html#method.with_graceful_shutdown) method can be used. You give it a future and when that future becomes ready, the HTTP service will stop accepting new connections, but will finish processing outstanding requests before terminating.